# setTimeout in the same function to whom it is calling?

Tags: javascript

I have learned that the setTimeout function runs once and the setInterval runs continuously after the specified time but when I am calling the setTimeout function in the same function it is calling it is behaving like the setInterval but when I am doing setInterval instead of set timeout it is behaving weird.
can anyone tell me what is happening to setTimeout and setInetval in function?

code with setTimeout

```js
function hello(){
  console.log("hello");
  setTimeout(hello,2000)
}
hello()
```

code with SetInterval

```js
function hello(){
  console.log("hello");
  setInterval(hello,2000)
}
hello()
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Everytime you call your function a new interval is added.

Comment: @alexP I am calling the function a single time why it s writing multiple times

Comment: Yeah but in your function you're starting an interval. The interval starts your function own its own after 2 seconds and starts another interval. Now you have 2 intervals, which starts your function. Each of this intervals starts a new interval. Now you have 4 intervals, ...

Comment: @alexP and could you define the second example(and if this question seems useful you can upvote this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In first example:**
Whenever `hello` method is called it registers a new timer to call hello after 2000ms. So, there will always be single call after 2000ms.

**In second example:**
Whenever hello is called it registers a new `setInterval` every time without terminating the previous `setInterval` which will result in new `setInterval` getting registered every time and you will get multiple logs on the console which will keep increasing every time `hello` is called.

Comment: If for some reason you want to use the second example, you can use `clearInterval()` to terminate the most previous setInterval

Comment: @Diwakar Singh  I am getting a little bit of your point but I am still confused on the second example(and if this question seems helpful you can upvote this)

Comment: @Diwakar Singh interrupt me if I am wrong like In the first example of setTimeout when I am calling the hello function the setTimeout is registered again and again (the hell function is called ant the setTimeout is called hello and in hello function has setTimeout and this process os running over and over again)_______and about the second example of  setInterval hen my function is called an interval is settled and the settled function multiples into 2,4,8 and so on

Comment: @DiwakarSingh I am in question ban (if this question seems useful to you can upvote this) it will encourage me

Comment: @DiwakarSingh can you please answer my other Javascript question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433538/settimeout-animation-problem-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment119191753_67433538 it seems complex

Answer (score 2):

- `setTimeout` allows us to run a function once.
- `setInterval` allows us to run a function repeatedly.

In your example, only one `setTimout` always exists, but `setInterval` creates one every 2000ms.

Comment: Thanks a lot (if this question seems useful to you can upvote this) it will encourage me

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that when there is setTimeout in the function, the asynchronous call stack will add a new function to be executed in the asynchronous call stack every time after the function is executed. Although setinterval also adds a function to be executed in the asynchronous call stack, the currently added function to be executed contains a setinterval, which means that there will be an exponential number when setinterval is executed The reason of "hello" output

You can execute the following code to facilitate your understanding：

```js
let count = 0

function hello() {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log("count:" + count++);
    setInterval(hello, 2000)
}

hello()
```

Answer (score 1):

In `setInterval` your your function will call in every 2 seconds as per your code.

```
function hello(){
  console.log("hello");
  setInterval(hello,2000)
}
hello()
```

Here `Hello()` called . And after 2 second again hello called with another setInterval(). It will called again hello method().
Though javascript is `asynchronous`, It will call thousands of `hello()` after sometime.
So this is not the right way to write setInterval.

You can write like this.

```
function hello() {
   console.log("hello");
}
setInterval(hello, 2000)
```

Now setInterval will call in every 2 seconds.

> Comment below, if you have any doubt

Comment: I get your point and thanks and could you define a little bit about asynchronous and if this question seems useful you can upvote this

Comment: I am adding another answer. So that I can describe it by demonstration

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment I will try to describe asynchronous briefly.

```
function methodOne() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("method one called");
    }, 5000)
}
function methodTwo() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("method two called");
    }, 2000)
}
methodOne()
methodTwo()
```

Now `methodOne()` will take 5 sec and `methodTwo()` will take 2 sec. And both will take 5 sec.
Lets see how:
first `methodOne()` called. Javascript will not wait for completion of execution of methodOne(). It will move to `methodTwo()`.
`MethodTwo()` will execute in 2 sec.
`MethodOne()` is still processing. After 3 sec; means while 5 sec complete `methodOne()` will complete execution.

So these two functions are not waiting for each other. It execute asynchronously.

Hope this will make you understand. Please comment below if you have any doubt.

Comment: what do you mean by "And both will take 5 sec" I think one will take 2sec and the other will take 5sec and the rest of this I get that. and I am in question ban(if this question seems helpful you can upvote this ) it highly encourages me

Comment: Actually I had to write that to complete both execution, it will take 5 sec.